# Lock an entire single table but still allow to access other tables in the same session on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, locking, table-locking, database-concurrency

Is it possible to lock a single table on MySQL for a session and still be able to read and write on other unlocked tables on the same session that locked that table while the table is still locked?

Comment: uh... yes? locks don't lock out entire connections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `LOCK TABLES` does exactly this.